# Unable to append to a find element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, append

I am running a check to see if the data-attribute, `availability` is Yes or No. If it is no, I am finding that specific `.smallCatalogBlock` and wanting to append the `.soonOverlay` on top of it.

As on now, the element is not being appended to `.smallCatalogBlock`. I have a console.log check in place to see if the condition is running successfully, and it is, with the correct number of found elements. The html just isn't being appended.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('availability') === 'No') {
    $(this).find('.smallCatalogBlock').append('<div class="soonOverlay"><div class="soonOverlayInner"><div class="total-center"><p class="dGw">Coming Soon</p></div></div></div>');
    console.log("It should be working");
  }
});
```

```css
.smallCatalogWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 60px 0;
}
.smallCatalogBlock {
 width: 25%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 20px auto;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.smallCatalogBlock img {
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
}
.smallCatalogTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.comingSoonSmall {
 position: relative;
}
.comingSoonSmall .soonOverlay {
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #b82222;
 opacity: .8;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0 10%;
}
.soonOverlayInner {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 350px;
}
.soonOverlayInner .dGw {
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogWrap">
  <div class="smallCatalogBlock" data-availability="Yes">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">A</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">B</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-availability="No">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">C</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are looking for `smallCatalogBlock` inside of `smallCatalogBlock`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because when you're using `$(this)`, the object itself is the item with class `.smallCatalogBlock`. So when you run `$(this).find('.smallCatalogBlock')`, it tries to find an element with class `smallCatalogBlock` WITHIN the element with class `smallCatalogBlock`, and fails. Since it can't find, it can't append. It should work if you simply do `$(this).append(...)`.

Comment: Wow...total mess up on my part. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great explanation!